# disable "up arrow" ability to pass through a cell?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I'm in text editing mode in a Jupyter notebook, I would like it so that pressing up when the cursor is on the first line of the cell doesn't transport me to the last line of the previous cell. Same for pressing down arrow when my cursor is at the bottom. Instead, I'd like the behavior in ordinary Jupyter notebooks, where pressing the up arrow brings you to the beginning of the cell.

Is there a way to do this?